# Intuition behind rotational analog's of motion

Tags: rotational-dynamics, momentum, conservation-laws, rotational-kinematics, intuition

Whenever I think of rotational analog's of motion , like angular velocity ,angular displacement and mainly angular momentum , something doesn't click with my intuition. Like I cant understand how they are substituted in kinematic equations of motions (v=u+at etc. as ω=ω₀+ αt etc ) whenever I intuitively think about this i cant get it .Can someone help me out?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to apply these concepts to that is resulting in confusion? Angular velocity measures the rate of rotation within a reference frame. Combined with a distance, angular velocity is easily converted into a translational velocity by multiplication. $v=r\omega$ is the standard equation given to highschoolers.

Comment: In substituting these new analog's in the newton's kinematic laws of motion , for example we use v=u+at (where v and u are final and initial velocities ) and as rotational analog we use ω=ω₀+ αt , with my intuition i cant understand how we can just substitute these values as they mean something different from original values. (im sorry if this is basic im trying to understand this for a very long time )

Comment: So what is your question? How to redefine Newton's Second Law in terms of angular velocity?

Comment: precisely how to intuitively understand kinematic equations in terms of rotational analogs of motion

Comment: @NaveenV Saying "I don't understand" something is too vague. You need to be more specific. If you like, think of a particular idea in rotational motion that you have a hard time understanding, and edit your question so that it asks of a specific concept. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? Velocity  (meters per sec) is like angular  velocity (rotations per sec)? One problem is finding how long it takes a given force to stop an object with a given mass and velocity. A similar problem  asks how long it takes a given torque to stop a flywheel with a given moment of inertia and angular velocity.

Comment: @mmesser314 no their substitutions in kinematic equations , how can we substitute them in kinematic equations an explanation in that regard

Comment: @josephh i have edited my question. thanks !

Comment: So you are looking for something like this? When a point travels in a circle, it has a velocity $v$, and an angular velocity $\omega = v/r$. You can get angular acceleration from $\alpha = \dot{\omega} = \dot{v}/r = a/r$.

Comment: yeah something like that @mmesser314 but the answer clarified it for me ! side note wouldnt alpha = omega/time to get a/r ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation is nothing but the arc distance traveled by a point, divided by its distance from the rotation axis.

Take any kinematic equation:

$$v_2=v_1+at$$

and divide by $r$, the distance from the axis of rotation to the point in question.

$$\frac {v_2}{r}=\frac {v_1} {r} +\frac a r t$$

$$\omega_2=\omega_1+\alpha t$$

They are the same equation, divided by a constant factor. You are still tracking the same motion of the same point, but changing how you are measuring it. And for rigid bodies it turns out this way of measuring makes the statement also valid for any point on that rigid body.

It is that simple.

Getting into the dynamics of rotational motion with torques, angular momentum, and cross products is a bit more complex, but that did not seem to be your question.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for , its just a constant factor brought into this equation makes us measuring a  different property right? and it makes sense numerically too thank you!!

Comment: Mathematically, $r$ is only _constant_ for a single point on a rigid body. In general $r=r(t)$ is a function of time and relates to the Cartesian coordinates via $r^2(t) = x^2(t) + y^2(t)$.